wifi slow when bluetooth is working in asus laptop
I have an Asus x555q with Ubuntu 22.04 and I tried to make internal bluetooth work with Wifi but just connecting bt makes the wifi speed falls to more than 50%.
I have read the guides here and here but they not worked at all.
any ideas?
BTW I'm bearing this problem with more than two years without find the answer.

Perhaps the wifi/bt card is broken. Perhaps the 2.4GHz band is saturated & it just so happens that the BT device is marking all channels bad & only using the frequency that the wifi card is operating on. Or perhaps the firmware/kernel code is broken.

After a lot of research about this particular network module and a lot of try and fix, I just created a file:
/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k-bt.conf

with this options:
options ath9k btcoex_enable=0

restarted and voila! It worked. No more slow wifi.
BTW, If there is any problem with bluetooth, I just restart
systemtctl restart bluetooth

and it worked again.
regards.

Bravo. .... "That research which does not kill us, only makes us stronger!" Thanks for sharing!
